# Как настроить 301 редирект с site.com/page1/ на site.com/page1

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно настроить 301 редирект со всех страниц со слешем в конце на те же страницы без слеша

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

Можете протестировать на https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

или можно попробовать

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```